# Как добавить свою переменную в input yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

В базе данных есть поле Name (в котором записаны имена будущих input).
В модели вытаскиваю все Name что есть и они записываются в массив.
В контроллере передаю этот массив на views.
В views/index файле нужно сделать форму, в которой будут checkbox с именами которые они получат из Name.

```
//$nameRecordsCount - это количество всех Name в базе

//$allNameEx - это массив с id и Name // То есть $allNameEx[$i]['name']; вернет например name1;

//И вот я тут хочу передать имя в строку после, $model, но я получаю ошибку //Attribute name must contain word characters only.
<?= $form->field($model, 'date')->widget(yii\jui\DatePicker::className(),['dateFormat' => 'yyyy-MM-dd'])?>

<?php for ($i = 0; $i < $nameRecordsCount; $i++) { ?>

    <?php $formName = (string)$allNameEx[$i]['name'];?>

    <?= $form->field($model, "$formName")->checkbox() ?>
```

Почему и как решать?

p.s извините за качество вопроса, не знаю пока как редактировать вставляемый код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php foreach($allNameEx as $nameEx) : ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, $nameEx['name'])->checkbox() ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Это хороший вариант без for, но все равно получаю 
 throw new InvalidParamException('Attribute name must contain word characters only.');

Comment: Ошибка говорит за себя, сделайте var_dump($allNameEx) или print_r($allNameEx) и покажите результат

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Name 1
            [id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Name 2
            [id] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Name 3
            [id] => 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Name 4
            [id] => 4
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => Name 5
            [id] => 5
        )

)
    print_r($allNameEx);

Comment: Я так понял, что оно ругается на символ $, а в throw new там стоит запрет на $

Comment: 'Name 1' - это имя атрибута? С пробелом?

Comment: Да, пробел нельзя?

Comment: Как вы себе представляете имя атрибута/свойства класса/поля в базе данных с пробелом?

Comment: Да, проблема была в пробелах, я Вам искренне благодарен за помощь,  если не сложно, подскажите в какую сторону искать, а то. все равно нужны записи с пробелами, как их обрабатывать?
Потому что эти имена в последующем будут выводиться на странице и как Lable чекбокса

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39664/discussion-between-alexandr-kalashnikov-and-fitstd).